# android.view.WindowLeaked on Asyctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a problem when try to run asynctask. The error appears sometimes, for example, if I run 20 times the asynctask the error appears 1 or 2. 
I think the problem is with the ProgressDialog (trying to close when there is no Dialog running) but I couldn't solved it .

The error log said:

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.app.GestionarTurnos has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{26d38b91 V.E..... R......D 0,0-160,180} that was originally added here
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:375)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                           at com.app.CalcularHorariosDisponiblesComplejo$CalcularHorariosComplejoAsyncTask.onPreExecute(CalcularHorariosDisponiblesComplejo.java:110)
```

This is my code of my asynctask from CalcularHorariosDisponiblesComplejo.java:

```
public MyAsyncTask(Context context, String idComplejoSeleccionado, String idCancha, String nombreComplejo, String idUsuarioComplejo, String idPais, String dia, String mes, String anio) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.idComplejoSeleccionado = idComplejoSeleccionado;
        this.idCanchaSeleccionada = idCancha;
        this.nombreComplejo = nombreComplejo;
        this.idUsuarioComplejo = idUsuarioComplejo;
        this.idPais = idPais;
        this.dia = Integer.parseInt(dia);
        this.mes = Integer.parseInt(mes);
        this.anio = Integer.parseInt(anio);

        Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(String.valueOf(65)));
        cl.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dia));
        cl.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(mes));
        cl.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(anio));
        this.dayOfWeek = cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.dialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo = null;
        fechaSeleccionada = (String.valueOf(anio)) + "-" + (String.valueOf(mes + 1)) + "-" + (String.valueOf(dia));

        try {
            jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo = JSONParser.readJsonFromUrl(url.concat(fechaSeleccionada+"&idCancha="+idCanchaSeleccionada+"&idUsuario="+idUsuarioComplejo+"&idComplejo="+idComplejoSeleccionado+"&dayOfWeek="+dayOfWeek+"&idPais="+idPais));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (!esCancelado) {
            if(jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo == null){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Not possible connect with the server. Try it again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SeleccionarCanchaComplejo.class);
                intent.putExtra("idComplejo", idComplejoSeleccionado);
                intent.putExtra("nombreComplejo", nombreComplejo);
                intent.putExtra("idPais", idPais);
                intent.putExtra("idUsuarioComplejo", idUsuarioComplejo);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
            }
            else{
                try {
                    // Verifica que se cargaron datos
                    int success;
                    success = jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        diaHoy = Integer.parseInt(jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getString(TAG_DIAHOY));
                        mesHoy = Integer.parseInt(jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getString(TAG_MESHOY));
                        anioHoy = Integer.parseInt(jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getString(TAG_ANIOHOY));
                        horaActual = jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getString(TAG_HORA);
                        todosLosTurnos = jsonCalcularHorariosComplejo.getJSONArray(TAG_TODOS_LOS_TURNOS);

                        for (int i = 0; i < todosLosTurnos.length(); i++) {
                            turnoAux = todosLosTurnos.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Guardo en variables los datos del objeto
                            String hora = turnoAux.getString(TAG_HORA);
                            int canchaFK = Integer.parseInt(turnoAux.getString(TAG_CANCHAFK));
                            int usuarioFK = Integer.parseInt(turnoAux.getString(TAG_USUARIOFK));
                            int reservado = Integer.parseInt(turnoAux.getString(TAG_RESERVADO));
                            String fecha = turnoAux.getString(TAG_FECHA);
                            String nombreAuxiliar = turnoAux.getString(TAG_NOMBREAUXILIAR);
                            int noAsistio = Integer.parseInt(turnoAux.getString(TAG_NOASISTIO));
                            String fechaDeReserva = turnoAux.getString(TAG_FECHADERESERVA);
                            String telefonoAux = turnoAux.getString(TAG_TELEFONO);
                            String estado = turnoAux.getString(TAG_ESTADO);
                            Turno turno = new Turno(hora, canchaFK, usuarioFK, reservado, fecha, nombreAuxiliar, noAsistio, fechaDeReserva, telefonoAux, estado);
                            todosMisTurnos.add(turno);
                        }
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Gestionar.class);
                intent.putExtra("todosMisTurnos", (ArrayList<Turno>) todosMisTurnos);
                intent.putExtra("idComplejo", idComplejoSeleccionado);
                intent.putExtra("idCancha", idCanchaSeleccionada);
                intent.putExtra("nombreComplejo", nombreComplejo);
                intent.putExtra("idUsuarioComplejo", idUsuarioComplejo);
                intent.putExtra("idPais", idPais);
                intent.putExtra("dia", String.valueOf(dia));
                intent.putExtra("mes", String.valueOf(mes));
                intent.putExtra("anio", String.valueOf(anio));
                intent.putExtra("diaHoy", String.valueOf(diaHoy));
                intent.putExtra("mesHoy", String.valueOf(mesHoy));
                intent.putExtra("anioHoy", String.valueOf(anioHoy));
                intent.putExtra("horaActual", horaActual);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to the error in the line java:110, is this line (on preexecute):
    this.dialog.show();

Somebody can help me?

Comment: is this `Context` parameter an `Activity`?

Comment: remove condition to dismiss the dialog and make sure you have **dialog.dismiss();** in first statement of **onPostExecute()**;

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one AsyncTask then start Progress Dialog mechanism will be changed like

First of All Do not Defined dialog.show() in  `onPreExceute()` and `onPostExecute()` when you have more than one Async task and step by step execution

**Rather than try to implement this things**

Start Progress Dialog in Main Thread

```
      Start Asynctask 1
      Start Asynctask 2

      Start Asynctask 20
```

At the response of Asynctask 20 dismiss Progress dialog in mainThread

In between no need to start And stop asynctask

it will work

Happy codding!!!

Comment: I have only one task. Also y call the asynctask from other activity sending the context

Comment: so i don't understand what were you facing problems dear?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

This is the problem. Put it at the start of your onPostExecute()

Comment: Still having the problem

Answer (score 0):

man, you are killing activity and then try to close dialog, first do all actions in activity and then at very end kill you activity.
here first this:

```
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

and only then

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

coz for now you killed activity, and then you are trying to close dialog in non exist activity.

Comment: i suppose you are calling this task multiple times? if so you must count instances you called in some value (increase on start and decrease on stop) - and kill activity only when last instance finish it's work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is well described here:

[Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

In general, I suggest you to take care with `AsyncTask`s that execute code in place of an `Activity`, like showing dialogs or finishing it, because it creates a strong link between the `AsyncTask` and the `Activity`. And, since the task is asynchronous to the activity, some problems may rise, for example, when the `Activity` no longer exists when `AsyncTask` finishes its background work, or when multiple `AsyncTask`s are dispatched from the same `Activity` at the same time.